# Can Android Wear(ex. moto 360) be a BT headset itself?

Tags: android, wear-os

Since Android Wear device equips BT, can it be connected to an Android phone and receive voice call or audio just like a BT headset ? I've tried to answer a voice call in watch(Moto 360), but conversation still has to be on the phone. I'm curios about if there's any technical gap on Android Wear ? Why there's no 3rd party App nor Android native App to fulfill this feature while Apple Watch did.

Answer (score 0):

Android Wear devices contain a microphone for speech recognition, but no speaker. So it is not possible to make phone calls like you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Android wear need to support BT headset profile.For now they dont support this profile.